# Make Rails's Validation Helpers return with false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Well, I've got this *simplified version* of a model(**Rails 3.2.13**):

```rb
class Transfer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :from,:to,:total
  validates_presence_of :from,:to,:total

  before_validation :positive_numbers, on: :create
  before_validation :check_enough_balance, on: :create
  after_validation :update_balances

  private
  def positive_numbers
    unless self.total>0
      errors.add(:total,"should be greater than 0")
      return false
    end
  end
  def check_enough_balance
    @sender=User.find(self.from)
    @receiver=User.find(self.to)
    unless @sender.enough_balance(self.total)
      errors.add(:base,"Not enough credit")
      return false
    end
  end
  def update_balances
    @sender.balance -= self.total
    @receiver.balance += self.total
    @sender.save
    @receiver.save
  end
  def another_action
    puts 'does something'
  end

end
```

Whenever `total<0`, the instance returns with a `false`, the `errors` array properly filled and `another_action` callback is not called.

I was wondering how to get this same behavior using Rails's built-in validation helpers, this is how I tried it:

```
class Transfer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :from,:to,:total
  validates_presence_of :from,:to,:total
  validates_numericality_of :total, greater_than: 0

  before_validation :check_enough_balance, on: :create
  after_validation :update_balances
  private

  def check_enough_balance
    @sender=User.find(self.from)
    @receiver=User.find(self.to)
    unless @sender.enough_balance(self.total)
      errors.add(:base,"Not enough credit")
      return false
    end
  end
  def update_balances
    @sender.balance -= self.total
    @receiver.balance += self.total
    @sender.save
    @receiver.save
  end
end
```

```rb
class User<ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username
  validates_presence_of  :username, :balance

  def enough_balance(amount)
    self.balance >= amount
  end

end
```

However in this case, since the validation helper does not `return false` the following custom validation `check_enough_balance` is called, I would like it to behave exactly the same, and I believe using validation helpers is somehow more elegant and concise.

Answer (score 2):

The `before_validation` callback literally means "run this method before checking validation." If you want your validations to run before `another_action` consider moving that to a different callback. Based on your example, I think you probably want the `after_validation` callback, but there are other supported callbacks that may work better too.

```
after_validation :another_action, on: :create
```

You can find the full list of supported callbacks here: [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Validation rules should be stand alone units that makes sense regardless of what your other rules do. It's generally best for all of the validation rules to run and gather all the combined errors so the user can fix everything at the same time.

For your specific case, checking that a user can cover a total of 0 or less seems perfectly fine. It's just another validation rule that is independent from the others. That said, consider moving that from a callback into an actual validator:

```
class Transfer < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validate :enough_balance

  private

  def enough_balance
    unless User.find(self.from).enough_balance(self.total)
      errors.add(:base, "Not enough credit")
    end
  end
end
```

If you need to not perform that check for some reasons (performance for example), it's easy enough to check again for the invalid condition without dealing with the errors at the same time by changing the condition to the following:

```
unless self.total <= 0 || User.find(self.from).enough_balance(self.total)
```

You can find more information about custom validators here: [Active Record Validations - Custom Validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators)

Saving records should never happen as part of validation (including before and after callbacks). None of us want that side effect if we, for example, just want to manually check if a record is valid:

```
transfer = Transfer.new(...)
if transfer.valid?
  # Stuff gets saved?!?!
  ...
end
```

Instead, use the `before_save` and `after_save` callbacks to update related records. Those callbacks will only run if `ActiveRecord` decides it is acceptable to save the records. Those callbacks will NOT be run if validation fails as part of a `save` call.

```
after_save :update_balances
```

Also, when performing extra saves in this way, it's generally best practice to use the `save!` method instead of the `save` method and wrap everything in a transaction. `save` should be used when you are explicitly checking the return value. `save!` should be used when you are assuming everything is in the state you expect. The exception raised by `save!` can be used to rollback all of your other changes made as part of that transaction.

Some examples:

```
transfer = Transfer.new(...)

if transfer.save # Good!
  ...

if transfer.save! # Bad, causes an exception when you might expect false
  ...

transfer.save # Bad, can silently fail

transfer.save! # Good, raises an exception if it unexpectedly fails

# All changes will be rolled back if any of the `save!` calls raise exceptions
Transfer.transaction do
  transfer.save!
  something_else.save!
  yet_another_thing.save!
end
```

You would usually put your `Transfer.transaction` call in the controller around the `transfer.save` or `transfer.save!` call.

More information about transactions can be found here: [ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: That's a good thought. But I forgot to mention that I need that callback to be called also **before** validation. I edited the example so the former `another_action` is now `check_enough_balance`, which checks for enough credit. I appreciate the reply tho.

Comment: @vint-i-vuit I think with your example, you should treat `check_enough_balance` as just another validator. See my edit for more information.

Comment: Again, I appreciate the reply. I edited the question extending the example( I guess I shouldn't have simplified it to start with), to show *why* I want the validations to stop as soon as one fails. As you can see I've got an `after_validation` method that I want to be run once all validations pass with no errors. The closest thing I've got using validation helpers is `after_validation :update_users_balance, if: :all_valid` where `def all_valid; self.errors.empty?; end`. However this for some reason **saves** the new `@transfer`, even if it's invalid. :/

Comment: @vint-i-vuit I added some more information related to validations/saving. I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: that is indeed very useful, I will have a closer look tomorrow and share some feedback, thanks :)